# UTC datetime conversion

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone, phpmyadmin

The values that I received from my device are: 090211 = ddmmyy and 062123 = hhmmss in UTC.

But I found that the time is always 8 hours later if compared to the time that I need. It is because the time for Malaysia is +8:00. First I would like to add 8 hour, and finally I would like to store this kind of date format into my MySQL database as "2011-02-09 06:21:23". How would I convert these values?

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert in PHP to a datetime, you will need the [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) `DateTime::createFromFormat();` This function will return a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). 
Using this function you can also pass the [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) as a parameter.

Example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy Gms', '090211 062123', new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam") );
```

You can create a output a following:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or UNIX timestamp for the MySQL:

```
echo $date->format('U');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Sir, actually i dont really understand the code. HAHA. why it is 'dmy Gms', '090211 062123' but not, 'ddmmyy' ? beside what is Gms stands for ?? thx

Comment: This is my coding :
echo("<br />");
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy Gms', '090211 062123', new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur") );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

and i get 2012-09-09 06:00:23 ? why it change into 2012 ? thx for guiding me

Comment: It differs from the normal PHP `date()` format. Please us this format [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Try: `DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy Gis', '090211 062123' );`, my mistake!

Comment: Dear Sir,it is working now, and i get the result 2011-02-09 06:21:23.
How if i wan the result to add +8 hour, so that i will give me result of 2011-02-09 14:21:23 ?? thx

Comment: Try: `$date->add( add DateInterval('P8H') );` Should work then ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has both [`localtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php) and [`gettimeofday`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php) functions, are you by chance using the wrong one (or misinterpreting its results)?

Comment: Actually i`m using this code
'code'
$the_date = strtotime("2010-01-19 12:01:20");
echo(date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date) . "<br />");
echo(date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur") . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $the_date) . "<br />");

and the result that i get is 

UTC
2010-19-01UTC12:01:2018
1
2010-19-01MYT20:01:2018

Actually this result is wrong ,it should be 2010-19-01MYT20:01:20, do u know wat happen??

Comment: Carefull with `strtotime()`, you don't explicitly define the format of the string. So the parser may mistake with the month/day notation.